# How to delete a single specific file from Picasso disk cache?

Tags: android, picasso

Is it possible to delete an image from Picasso disk cache by its url? So far I figured out how to delete it from the memory cache and how to wipe the disk cache.

Couldn't find at what point Picasso saves files to disk and how it picks filenames (they look like random unique ids) so I would delete them manually.